# How can I extract the unmatched portion of a string in R with regular expressions?

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I have a vector of extremely messy strings. Here is an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
strings <- tibble(
  name = c("lorem 11:07:59 86136-1-sed", 
           "ipsum 14:35:57 S VARNAME-ut",
           "dolor 10:37:53 1513 -2-perspiciatis",
           "sit 10:48:25",
           "amet 13:52:1365293-2-unde",
           "consectetur 11:53:1 16018-2-omnis",
           "adipiscing 11:19 17237-2-iste"
           )
)
strings_out <- strings %>% 
  mutate(heads = str_extract(name, "^.*?\\s\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}")) %>% 
  mutate(ends = str_replace(name, "^.*?\\s\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}", ""))
strings_out[,2:3]
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>                 heads                          ends
#>                 <chr>                         <chr>
#> 1      lorem 11:07:59                   86136-1-sed
#> 2      ipsum 14:35:57                  S VARNAME-ut
#> 3      dolor 10:37:53          1513 -2-perspiciatis
#> 4        sit 10:48:25                              
#> 5       amet 13:52:13                  65293-2-unde
#> 6 consectetur 11:53:1                 16018-2-omnis
#> 7                <NA> adipiscing 11:19 17237-2-iste
```

So here I have strings that feature some text, followed by a time that may or may not be entered correctly, then some more text. I want to extract just the ends of the strings after the time, however they do not have any pattern that seems to correspond well to a potential regular expression using `str_extract`. I can easily match the first half of the strings, shown in `heads`. However, the only way that I found to extract the last half is to use `str_replace` with an empty string, as shown in `ends`.

I tried to include all the common errors that I noticed in this list: no pattern as to the hyphenation, spacing or string contents after the time, no guaranteed space betwene the time and the desired end half of the string, times missing digits or even colons.

What I would like to do is to be able to use `str_extract` to get something close to what I got with `str_replace`. The key difference is that for the errors where this regex still does not work, `str_extract` gives me an `NA` that is easy to filter for and fix manually, but `str_replace` just copies in the whole string as seen in row 7.

I suspect I could do this with some more hacky methods, like getting all the `NA` and fixing manually in Excel or something, but I was surprised that I could not figure out how to return the unmatched portion of a string in general despite a bunch of searching and trying different regular expressions that include `(^)` and `[^]`. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. Desired result is the second column except returning NA wherever the first column has one. I realise that I could just go through and replace them with `NA` at the correct indices, but I found it puzzling that the concept of "return the unmatched portion of the string" seemed to be hard to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you'll probably want to look into [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but your data might need more structure for them to be useful.

Here's a quick example I wrote before realizing the time doesn't always have a space after it:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
strings <- tibble(
  name = c("lorem 11:07:59 86136-1-sed", 
           "ipsum 14:35:57 S VARNAME-ut",
           "dolor 10:37:53 1513 -2-perspiciatis",
           "sit 10:48:25",
           "amet 13:52:1365293-2-unde",
           "consectetur 11:53:1 16018-2-omnis",
           "adipiscing 11:19 17237-2-iste"
  )
)
strings_out <- strings %>% 
  mutate(heads = str_extract(name, "^.*?\\s\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}"),
         ends = str_extract(name, "(?<=:\\d{1,2} )[\\s\\S]+$"))

strings_out[c(1,3)]
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>                                  name                 ends
#>                                 <chr>                <chr>
#> 1          lorem 11:07:59 86136-1-sed          86136-1-sed
#> 2         ipsum 14:35:57 S VARNAME-ut         S VARNAME-ut
#> 3 dolor 10:37:53 1513 -2-perspiciatis 1513 -2-perspiciatis
#> 4                        sit 10:48:25                 <NA>
#> 5           amet 13:52:1365293-2-unde                 <NA>
#> 6   consectetur 11:53:1 16018-2-omnis        16018-2-omnis
#> 7       adipiscing 11:19 17237-2-iste         17237-2-iste
```

The problem here is lines like line 5. Without more structure, we can't know if the time is `13:52:13` or `13:52:1`, as both are options present in other strings. Figuring out which is correct is not a problem that can be solved with regular expressions.

Comment: Hmm ok I see what you mean about line 5. As far as I can tell, when the time is followed by numbers there aren't more than five of them, which is why I wrote the regex as I did. I think the lookbehind is a tool i wasn't aware of before, which does allow the use of `str_extract` as I wanted. I guess there might not be a good way to "extract unmatched and it just requires modifying the regex to find the desired match?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

regex = "^\\w+\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:*\\d{0,2}"

strings %>%
  mutate(head = str_extract(name, regex),
         end = str_replace(name, paste0(regex, "\\s?"), ""),
         end = str_replace(end, "^\\s*$", NA_character_))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
                                 name                head                  end
                                <chr>               <chr>                <chr>
1          lorem 11:07:59 86136-1-sed      lorem 11:07:59          86136-1-sed
2         ipsum 14:35:57 S VARNAME-ut      ipsum 14:35:57         S VARNAME-ut
3 dolor 10:37:53 1513 -2-perspiciatis      dolor 10:37:53 1513 -2-perspiciatis
4                        sit 10:48:25        sit 10:48:25                 <NA>
5           amet 13:52:1365293-2-unde       amet 13:52:13         65293-2-unde
6   consectetur 11:53:1 16018-2-omnis consectetur 11:53:1        16018-2-omnis
7       adipiscing 11:19 17237-2-iste    adipiscing 11:19         17237-2-iste
```

**Note:**

My solution works for row 5, but you will have to decide whether you want to extract `13:52:13` or `13:52:1` in this case. Either cases can be done with simple modification to the regex, but as stated by @Zach, there is no automatic way.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it with just one additional line:

```
strings["rx"] <- str_match(strings$name, "\\d*:\\d*(?::\\d+)?(.*)")[,2]
strings
```

Which yields

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
                                 name                    rx
                                <chr>                 <chr>
1          lorem 11:07:59 86136-1-sed           86136-1-sed
2         ipsum 14:35:57 S VARNAME-ut          S VARNAME-ut
3 dolor 10:37:53 1513 -2-perspiciatis  1513 -2-perspiciatis
4                        sit 10:48:25                      
5           amet 13:52:1365293-2-unde               -2-unde
6   consectetur 11:53:1 16018-2-omnis         16018-2-omnis
7       adipiscing 11:19 17237-2-iste          17237-2-iste
```

Comment: what about row 5?